# How to update an object with state where associated attributes need updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Pardon the cumbersome wording, I've tried my best to clarify this but in short: I'm running react 16 and not using redux or any state management library; only the useState hook in this case.

I have a `currentUser` being fetched from rails backend, which has an array of `concerts` and an array of `posts`. A `user` can make a `post` on a `concert`. The user on the frontend is going to either create a post or delete a post. I can successfully get the `currentUser.posts` to render immediately but the `currentUser.concerts` only updates after a manual refresh/reload.

The thing is the currentUser JSON object for my authentication has the full updates perfectly, but it's more the issue that state doesn't update immediately since I'm only updating currentUser.posts and working with the `post` JSON when I'm deleting or creating -- which is why I'm looking for a proper solution to this problem.

It's for a school project and I don't have the most time left so I can't look into implementing Redux or a state management solution afaik. The way I see it conceptually, I'd basically have to write out more code in the .then(response => ()) in order to filter out the concerts associated with that post:

- Deleting a post

If the deletedPost was the only post for a given concert for currentUser then delete the concert as well, otherwise if the deletedPost still has another "sibling" on the concert then don't delete that concert from currentUser.concerts.

- Creating a post

Similar to above but just in the other direction; if this post is the first one for this concert, add this concert to currentUser.concerts, otherwise keep currentUser.concerts as is.

**The commented space in the code below is where I figure the solution would be but I want to make sure there's a better way and a non-sloppy way to do this, because my way I imagine is the sloppier way.**

So to speak, here's what's going on:

*within createNewPost.js*

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetch('/posts', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        body: body,
        for_sale: isSelling,
        tickets: ticketAmount,
        concert_id: concert.id,
        user_id: currentUser.id,
      }),
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 299) {
        response.json().then((createdPost) => {
          setCurrentUser({
            ...currentUser,
            posts: [...currentUser.posts, createdPost],
          });
          //  here is also where the associated concert must be added,
          //  if it doesn't already exist
          //  symmetric to the handleDelete problems

          // first thought:
          // find the concert in currentUser that matches the concert_id on createdPost; if that concert is empty

          setErrorArray([]);
          setErrorsExist(false);
          setSuccess('Your post has been created!');
          setSubmitted(true);
        });
      } else {
        response.json().then((e) => {
          setErrorsExist(true);
          setErrorArray(e.errors);
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

*and within DeleteConfirmation.js:*

```
  function handleDelete(post) {
    fetch(`/posts/${post.id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    }).then(() => {
      // console.log('post in handleDelete: ', post);
      // console.log('currentUsers posts:', currentUser.posts);
      const updatedPosts = currentUser.posts.filter(
        (eachPost) => eachPost.id !== post.id
      );
      //! here one writes the steps to remove any associated concerts as well
      setCurrentUser({ ...currentUser, posts: updatedPosts });
      // console.log('currentUser: ', currentUser);
      // const associatedConcert = currentUser.concerts.find(
      //   (eachConcert) => eachConcert.id === post.concert_id
      // );
      // console.log('associatedConcert: ', associatedConcert);

      // find the concert that matches the post.concert_id
      // if that concert doesnt exist (make sure n = 0) then update the updatedConcerts in the same way as updatedPosts, and update the remaining concerts
      // if that concert still has remaining posts, then dont delete it
    });
  }
```

EDIT: Answered the question below, for anybody running into similar issues.

Comment: Its clear the strategy you are trying to implement here is make changes to the backend then modify the user object to reflect the difference. This is fine, and that is what `setCurrentUser` should do. I think you are just simply incorrectly modifying your user state and it is only corrected when your application reloads and fetch's the correct shape of your user data. If you log out your user state in each render, I think you will see a difference after your `setCurrentUser` call, it just wont be the change you expect.

Comment: @damonholden I'm a relative rookie to React (only ~6 months of experience) so I'm open to any improvements and a proper way to approach this problem. I'm all ears for any suggestions you have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's how I handled it:

*within the CreateNewPost.js*

```
  response.json().then((createdPost) => {
      const concertExists = currentUser.concerts.some(
        (concert) => concert.id === createdPost.concert_id
      );

      if (!concertExists) {
        const concertToAdd = concerts.find(
          (anyConcert) => anyConcert.id === createdPost.concert_id
        );

        setCurrentUser({
          ...currentUser,
          posts: [...currentUser.posts, createdPost],
          concerts: [...currentUser.concerts, concertToAdd],
        });
      } else if (concertExists) {
        setCurrentUser({
          ...currentUser,
          posts: [...currentUser.posts, createdPost],
        });
      }})
```

*within the handleDelete:*

```
  function handleDelete(post) {
    fetch(`/posts/${post.id}`, {
      method: 'DELETE',
    }).then(() => {
      const updatedPosts = currentUser.posts.filter(
        (eachPost) => eachPost.id !== post.id
      );
      const remainingPostsForConcert = currentUser.posts.filter(
        (eachPost) =>
          eachPost.concert_id === post.concert_id && eachPost.id !== post.id
      );

      if (remainingPostsForConcert.length === 0) {
        const updatedConcerts = currentUser.concerts.filter(
          (concert) => concert.id !== post.concert_id
        );

        setCurrentUser({
          ...currentUser,
          posts: updatedPosts,
          concerts: updatedConcerts,
        });
      }
    });
  }
```